# Database side paging

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, paging

I need to use database side paging like if a table has 10,000 records then i have to fatch 100 record first then further 100 record.I am using SQL Server 2005  Please provide stored procedure code for this.

Comment: Requires (free) registration but covered well in this two part series http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/paging/69892/

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function available since SQL Server 2005.

It has proven to be the most efficient way (in my case) to do server-side paging.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1 ASC) AS rownbr
    FROM table
    WHERE col2 = 'something'
) AS Query
WHERE rownbr BETWEEN 1 AND 10
ORDER BY rownbr
```

You can set the columns you want to order by in the OVER() statement and the first and last row you want to retrieve in the outer WHERE statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @PageSize INT,  
    @PageNumber INT,  
    @FirstRow INT,  
    @LastRow INT  

SELECT  @PageSize = 20,  
          @PageNumber = 1     


SELECT  @FirstRow = ( @PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + 1,  
    @LastRow = (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + @PageSize ;  

WITH Members  AS  
(  
    SELECT  Col1,Col2,Col3,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1 DESC) AS RowNumber  
                FROM    Table  
)  
SELECT  Col1,Col2,..,..,..,
FROM    Members  
WHERE   RowNumber BETWEEN @FirstRow AND @LastRow  
ORDER BY Col1 ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually try to page where you have page numbers, then you can do something like the following:

```
Create Procedure GetPagedStuff( @PageNumber int, @PageSize int )
As

;With RankedRows As
    (
    Select ...
        , Row_Number() Over ( Order By SomeColumn ) As Num
        , Count( NonNullColumn ) Over() As TotalRows
    From MyTable
    )
Select ...
From RankedRows
Where Num > (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize
    And Num <= @PageNumber * @PageSize

Return

-- example call
Exec GetPagedStuff @PageNumber = 1, @PageSize = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Jason and Thomas, ROW_NUMBER() function is your best bet. But if the number of records fulfilling the WHERE clause is very high, you may want to just retrieve the primary key and then joining the subset with the same table again to get the other columns.

Eg:

```
SELECT e.col1, e.col2, e.col3
FROM Table1 e
JOIN 
(SELECT ID, rownum= ROW_NUMBER()
FROM Table1
WHERE col1 = @filterParam
ORDER BY LastName) 
f ON f.ID = e.ID
WHERE f.rownum BETWEEN 100 AND 150
```